# Load columns with code in kendo grid using kendo's column chooser

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Check out the stackblitz I've prepared [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbekff).

Using the `ColumnChooserComponent` as shown above, I'd like to achieve 2 things:

1. Find out what columns are currently visible.
2. Using a `string[]` with
   the names of columns, I'd like to programmatically show/hide
   columns.

The goal is to eventually store these values in a server somewhere as `json` and then load them depending on what settings the user has. I've read the documentation ([grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid) and [column chooser](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnChooserComponent/)) but all I've gotten so far is just a list of *all* columns, with no idea which are visible and which are not. Ideally, I'd like you to complete the functions I've left blank in the stackblitz, `logVisible` and `loadFromArray`, with the functionality I've described above.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: The answer I was looking for is user **StepUp**'s Update 1.

**UPDATE 2 AND CLARIFICATIONS**: The solution I ended up using looks like my answer below.

For anyone interested in this in the future, it turns out what the `ColumnChooserComponent` does is simply set the `hidden` property of each `ColumnBase` element in the grid. These are accessed from `grid.columnList` (assuming `grid` is the `GridComponent` reference). Use `forEach` to iterate and `toArray` if you just want to them all in memory. What this means is you can hook any kind of custom solution you want in the UI if you don't like the default `ColumnChooserComponent`. Useful to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create a string array of desired columns and just show them when you load your grid:

```
testCols: string[] = ['ProductID', 'ProductName', 'QuantityPerUnit'];
```

And html:

```
<kendo-grid #grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410">
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="testCols" let-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="{{column}}">
            <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-dataItem>
                {{dataItem.field}}
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <p> {{ dataItem[column] | json }} </p>
            </ng-template>    
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

[A stackblitz example can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbekff-rvuvht?file=app/app.component.html)

**UPDATE:**

Then you can use `hidden` property of `kendo-grid-column`.

So you can create an array of `hiddenColumns` and then just push the columns which should be hidden.

Then after user settings are saved, you can push hidden columns into `hiddenColumns`.

TypeScript:

```
public hiddenColumns: string[] = [];
```

HTML:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" style="height:400px">
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>
        <kendo-grid-column
            field="{{column}}"
            [hidden]="hiddenColumns.indexOf(column) > -1"
         >
         <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{dataItem.field}}
             <button
               (click)="hideColumn(dataItem.field)"
                class="k-button k-primary"
                style="float: right;"
             >
             Hide
             </button>
          </ng-template>
       </kendo-grid-column>
   </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

[A grid example with hide button can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpgavf?file=app/app.component.ts)

**UPDATE 1:**

You can create an array of `choosenColumns`:

```
choosenColumns: any[] = [];

// Use this function to console.log currently visible columns.
public logVisible = (grid) => {
    if (this.choosenColumns.length == 0) {
    this.choosenColumns = grid.columnList.columns._results
        .filter(f => f.isVisible)
        .map(s=> s.field);        
    }
}

 // Use this function to load columns from a string[].
 public loadFromArray = () => {      
    this.grid.columnList.columns._results.forEach(c => {
        if (!this.choosenColumns.includes(c.field)) {          
           c.hidden = false;
          console.log(c.field, c.hidden);
        } 
    })    
 }
```

[An work example with kendo-grid-column-chooser at stackblitz can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbekff-8qo1un?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This does not use the column chooser (or any way of choosing columns). I want to give the option, after first load, to show/hide columns AND have the ability to save the configuration.

Comment: Like I said, I would like this to be done with the column chooser component, not a custom solution. If people tell me this can't be done, I will probably use something like your solution. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had in mind. I'm surprised that kendo doesn't provide a more "built in" way to do this. I haven't found it, if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly better approach than what user StepUp is proposing. Their solution accesses private properties of the `ColumnList` class, which is bad practice. I have found a way using only publicly accessible properties.

In the stackblitz above, I completed the functions `logVisible` and `loadFromArray` as follows:

```js
  // Use this function to console.log currently visible columns.
  public logVisible = () => {
    const visible = this.grid.columnList
      .filter(c => c.hidden !== true)
      .map(c => c.title);
    console.log(visible);
  };

  // Use this function to load columns from a string[].
  public loadFromArray = () => {
    const testCols: string[] = ["ID", "Name", "Discontinued"];
    this.grid.columnList.forEach(c => {
      if(!testCols.includes(c.title)) {
        c.hidden =  true;
      }
    })
  };
```

New stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbekff-hhgqes

**Important note:** When trying to find visible columns, I highly recommend using the check `c.hidden !== true`, since by default the `hidden` property of `ColumnBase` is `undefined`, not `false`! This took me a while to figure out; I was checking with `!c.hidden` getting wrong results and couldn't figure out what was going on.